# jquery capturing text of selected id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If I have id's of the form: `t_*` where * could be any text, how do I capture the click event of these id's and be able to store the value of * into a variable for my use?

Comment: Note my comments on accepted answer and execption where it does not work when using the split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ***starts with*** selector `^=` like this:

```
$('element[id^="t_"]').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Where `element` could be any element eg a `div`, `input` or whatever you specify or you may even leave that out:

```
$('[id^="t_"]').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**Update:**

```
$('[id^="t_"]').click(function(){
  var arr = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
  alert(arr[1]);
});
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: thanks, this alerts the full 't_*' string.   How can I get only *?

Comment: $(this).attr('id').substr(1);

Comment: Well not exactly precise try the id string "t_myt_endit".  See my answer for getting just the beginning of the ID attribute.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: I knew that, assumed as OP says it is in **t_x** format but thanks anyways :)

Comment: Yes so your answer on the string I indicated gives "my" not "myt_endit" as the OP says "any text" (not beating on you, just giving an explaination for others as I see you know that :))

Answer (score 0):

```
var CurrentID = $(this).attr('id');
var CurrentName = CurrentID.replace("t_", "");
```

That should help with the repalce.

Comment: replace("t_", ""); does not work with id of "t_myidt_endit" as that gives "myidendit" not "myidt_endit"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// handle the click event of all elements whose id attribute begins with "t_"
$("[id^='t_']").click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    // handle the click event here
});
```

Comment: half the answer, nothing to get the character string for the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id^='t_']").click(function() 
{ 
    var idEnding = $(this).attr("id");
    idEnding.replace(/\t_/,''); 

});
```

Using the click event capture the ID that begins with t_, then replace that with nothing giving a capture the end of the ID value.